# how to Deploy the sencha touch app to iOS app in windows7

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using sencha touch 2.2.1

I have doubt to config a sencha app to iOS app in windows7.

I already deployed the sencha touch app to android app its works well. My problem is I don't have MAC-OS. so, can I deploy sencha app to iOS app in windows7 alone with apple-ID, certificate path and key values in sencha config file.

pls anyone tell me thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just set up a `packager.json` file as it is described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/native_packaging) and use `sencha app build native` in your command line to build your native iOS app.

If it does not work you could use the [PhoneGap-Cloud-Build-Service](http://phonegap.com/). You'll find information about how to set up cordova / phonegap in this [video](http://vimeo.com/76568053).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build all your apps in XCode 5 from February 1st which will require a mac.

source: https://developer.apple.com/ios7/

I saw this service yesterday which I haven't looked into myself, but may allow you to compile apps in the cloud using one of their macs, rather than have to buy one yourself at great cost : http://www.macincloud.com/